# Publishing shapefile on localhost

Tags: geoserver

I need to add stores (shapefiles) to geoserver running on localhost:8080. In data_dir/data I have directories containing shapefiles. I add them as workspaces with Namespace URI set to `localhost:8080/geoserver/data/*name_of_the_dir*/`.

When I try to add new store, the URL field in Connection Parameters doesn't open though and I can't choose which shapefile I want to add. I suppose the only error might be in `localhost:8080/geoserver/data/*name_of_the_dir*/`. I tried many different variations of this path, none of them worked for me.

So the question is rather simple (hope the answer too): How do I add a store to a workspace when working in localhost? Thanks for any help.

PS: The geoserver I'm working on is meant to run offline, thus I can't enter web URLs in Namespace URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Namespace URI can be any value you want provided that it is unique (at least) for your install.

The URL field in the Store tab is the path to the shapefile you are trying to load - it has nothing to do with the Workspace URI. The easiest way to fill it is to use the browse button and navigate to the file of interest. Or you can enter a relative (to the GeoServer data dir) or absolute path to the shapefile - including the file.shp part.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't get the browse button. I do when using the geoserver we run online, but with the one for offline use, the browser button is just no there.

Comment: just use *name_of_the_dir* then

Comment: Yes, that works. What I just found is the button is missing in Coordinate Reference Systems dialogue of the layer as well. Thus I can't choose the crs of a shapefile (nor enter it manually, as the input field is protected). What can be causing this problem?

Comment: Sounds like your install of GeoServer is broken somehow, try reinstalling it

Comment: The button is visible with the clean installation, I get nullpointerexception when selecting declared crs though. Gonna try another version. Thank you anyway.